# How to fix AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'toChecksumAddress'?

Tags: python, web3py

I'm trying to use 1inch oracle methods from [here](https://github.com/RichardAtCT/1inch_wrapper). This is python wrapper around 1inch apis. I want to know token price from some oracle so i'm using oracle method "get_rate_to_ETH".

But in a result I have this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\1inchArb\1inch_api.py", line 20, in <module>
    price_usdc = oracle.get_rate_to_ETH("0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48", src_token_decimal=6)
  File "D:\projects\1inchArb\venv\lib\site-packages\oneinch_py\main.py", line 376, in get_rate_to_ETH
    rate = self.oracle_contract.functions.getRateToEth(self.w3.toChecksumAddress(src_token), wrap).call()
AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'toChecksumAddress'
```

My code:

```
from oneinch_py import OneInchOracle


public_key = "my_wallet_addr"
rpc_url = "https://cloudflare-eth.com"

oracle = OneInchOracle(rpc_url, chain='ethereum')

price_usdc = oracle.get_rate_to_ETH("0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48", src_token_decimal=6)
```

Also I tried to use different RPC urls such as  "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{}".format(my_infura_key) but it gives same error.

If anyone knows how to help me it would be very grateful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to latests version оf `1inch.py` - 1.9, released 20 March 2023 and also `web3` to use version 6.0.0.

`1inch.py` is using `web3` as dependency. `web3` [removed CamelCase naming](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v6_migration.html#snake-case) in latest version 6.0.0

`1inch.py` released new version to change their code and migrate to using web3, version 6.0.0.